# Rails Associations - Associating a list of items with a particular user for a particular event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm working on an event site where users have items in their inventory that can be listed in their profile. For this I am using:

```
has_many :items
```

in my user.rb.

A user would then be able to attend any number of events. For each event, they would have a unique items list, i.e., items to bring to the event. I'm trying to figure out the associations in order to make this work.

In item_list.rb:

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
has_many :items
```

In item.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :item_list
```

In event.rb

```
has_many :item_lists
```

But what's baffling me is making sure that each list is unique to each event and user. Additionally, would my migration for `item_list` include an array of items?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What you mean by *would my migration for item_list include an array of items?*

Comment: When I generate my database migration for item_list, would I need to include a column of arrays, i.e. to hold item_ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what's baffling me is making sure that each list is unique to each
>   event and user.

If I'm not wrong, you are looking for [*`validates_uniqueness_of`*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) with `scope` option.

In your `item_list.rb`, add

```
validates_uniqueness_of :event_id, scope: :user_id
```

This will ensure you have an `item_list` with unique `event_id` and `user_id`. In other words, each `item_list` is unique to each `event` and `user`.

> When I generate my database migration for item_list, would I need to
>   include a column of arrays, i.e. to hold item_ids

No, with how your associations are setup Rails will expect you to have `item_list_id` in `items` table. So if you want fetch `items` for an `item_list`, you would do `@item_list.items`

Comment: Thank you, I think this mostly gets me there. I am running into a problem where when I try to create a new item before adding it to an item_list, I'm getting an error: "1 error prohibited this item from being saved: Item_list must exist". Any idea how to be able to create an item before the item_list is created so I can add it to the item_list later?

Comment: Nevermind, I actually figured it out, by changing my item.rb 

belongs_to :item_list, optional: true